# How can I load next 5 rows in dynamic database?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to select next 5 rows relative to the last row?

Example:
I have table **Products**, records could be adding by users by their own. I need to make some pagination products, for example show 5 products and show button load more. After button click I will send an Ajax request and load 5 more products.

Table Products (id):

> 10, 12, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 18, 19

At this moment user can see products with ID 10, 12, 9, 8, 4

Before user click on show next 5 products, another user will add product with id 20 (for example). Now in table I have new product

> 20, 10, 12, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 18, 19

When user click show next 5 products, I want to show next products, so products with ID 3, 2, 1, 18, 19, so I want to ignore new row with ID 20 and start after last product.

I can't use mysql `SELECT` with `LIMIT`, because at this moment in table Products is another count of rows.

Are there some SQL queries, which allow me to run `SELECT * FROM products WHERE {..} LIMIT {..}` and start after my last product?

Comment: I suggest you to order by DATETIME or `id` (PRIMARY KEY). When you do this, subsequent inserts will not alter the current product order, so you can avoid to deal with this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a field to the product called `create_date` for example, where you store the time when the product was created.

This will allow you to filter for:

```
WHERE create_date < $initalSearchTimestamp
LIMIT 5, 10
```

Where `$initalSearchTimestamp` will need to be part of your PHP code.

MySQL itfelf does not have the information what was the version of the product table the last time the user searched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution occurred to me. But user could filter products by the newest (this solution), oldest (same solution), but also by the price. There is a problem that price could be the same by 2 or more products, so the price isn't unique and I can't select this way.

Comment: In any of these cases the $initalSearchTimestamp filter would be an additional filter to the one the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can define from which position and how much rows the MySQL should to take.

Take a look into documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

> LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```